# "XXX is hashed" meaning from type command?

Tags: command-line, bash, windows

I realized that you can use windows `dir` in ubuntu terminal, when I tried to dig deeper into its implementation, `type` command tells me it is **hashed**, I read some [doc](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Type_command) but it didn't explain what "hashed" means

[image]

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105876/what-does-rm-is-hashed-mean.

Comment: [Why does `type which` say that `which is hashed`?](http://askubuntu.com/q/446580/253474)

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105878 by user [frostschutz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30851/frostschutz) on Unix Stackexchange:

> It's a performance thing; instead of searching the whole path for the binary every time it is called, it's put into a hash table for quicker lookup. So any binary that's already in this hash table, is hashed. If you move binaries around when they're already hashed, it will still try to call them in their old location.
>
> See also `help hash`, or `man bash` and search for `hash` under builtin commands there.