# How to change path for command

Tags: bash, paths

I had a self-compiled program installed on my computer. Tried to delete it by removing all of the folders and files, including the binaries located in `usr/local/bin/`.

I reinstalled the program from the Ubuntu stable PPA, so now the binaries are in `/usr/bin/`.

However, when I type the command, in my case `ogrinfo --version` or `gdal-config --version`, I get the following output:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ogrinfo: No such file or directory
```

If I run `type ogrinfo`, I get back:

```
ogrinfo is hashed (/usr/local/bin/ogrinfo)
```

How do I tell my system to now look for the package in `/usr/bin/` instead of `/usr/local/bin`?

**Additional Info**

When I was installing the program the first time from source, I did enter these commands which I think may be part of the problem (which I admittedly don't really know what they do exactly)

```
ldconfig
export PATH=$HOME/gdal-compile/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/gdal-compile:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tell `hash` to forget the locations:

```
hash -r
```

From `help hash`:

```
Options:
  -r    forget all remembered locations
```

More info: [Why does `type which` say that `which is hashed`?](https://askubuntu.com/q/446580/301745)